# Neo4j REST path example in movie project

Tags: neo4j

I am looking at the Neo4j movie sample project:

https://github.com/neo4j-examples/movies-java-spring-data-neo4j-4

Two of the **REST** endpoints are :

```
localhost:8080/movies/search/findByTitle?
localhost:8080/movies/search/findByTitleContaining?
```

I see that the "`movies`" part of the path is defined in `MovieRepository.java`, but where is the "`search`" part coming from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the page you linked to states:

> The other two endpoints for finding multiple movies by title and
>   loading a single movie are provided out of the box by the
>   [Spring-Data-Rest](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-rest/) project which exposes our MovieRepository as REST
>   endpoints.

See [Customizing Spring Data REST](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#repository-resources.search-resource) for some more info on tailoring Spring Data REST.

And [here is the relevant `CrudRepository`](https://github.com/neo4j-examples/movies-java-spring-data-neo4j-4/blob/master/src/main/java/movies/spring/data/neo4j/repositories/MovieRepository.java) in the movies example.